# How to I track down this problem when I try to CIVIMail? Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved

Tags: civimail

[image: Sorry and error occurred and your information was not saved.]

While in CiviMail I keep getting this message

"Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved."

Comment: Unfortunately it's a generic error message. Can you give more details about what is happening "in CiviMail" at that moment? Or add a `console.trace();` line in here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.15.2/js/Common.js#L1055 to get some info in the javascript console about what triggered it?

Comment: The extension Log Viewer makes it v easy to see errors via the UI https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: I have added the log viewer and nothing new appears in the log when this happens.

Comment: Actually I am seeing a lot of these in the log

[info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

Comment: = #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php(398): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->permissionDenied()
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(229): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

Comment: New Mailing
TYPE IN A Mailing Name
Wait a few seconds and the error happens

Comment: access.log says this when the error happens.

47.14.90.19 - - [07/Aug/2019:19:31:50 -0400] "POST /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/rest HTTP/1.1" 200 841 "https://massgunrights.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your firewall settings?
The wordfence plugin (on WordPress) was doing that for us. Had to white list the params.
Also, can be an error in the html of your email (or a smarty error).
As @demerit said it's a generic error and can be plenty of things.